# Magento | Add border for a specific product in in the products' table of order confirmation email

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, php, order-email

How can we add a border for the tbody of a specific product in the products table of order email template?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how you know a product is a "specific" product. 
If, for example, this product has a special sku `special-sku`, then you can achieve it by modifying your custom `/email/order/items/order/default.phtml` template (copy the file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml` in your theme).

In this template, you can get the product infos with `$_product = $_item->getProduct();`.

Then you can decide to add a border or whatever you want by testing with :

```
<?php if($_product->getSku() == 'special-sku'): ?>
// Add custom design here
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can do the same thing in a custom `email/order/items.phtml` template (here is the `tbody` declaration).

Edit : after writing this, I just saw that the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item` has a `getSku()` method : so, you don't even have to get the product with the `$_item->getProduct()` call. You can just test with a `if($_item->getSku() == 'special-sku')`. I don't erase my first message because the `$_item->getProduct()` call could be usefull if you have to check if a product is a special product with any other specific attribute.